# Prove that the Weiertrass function is biperiodic

Tags: complex-analysis, elliptic-functions

I am reading the chapter on elliptic functions in complex analysis by ahlfors, who used the following formula in his argument that the Weiertrass function is biperiodic
We let
$$\wp＝\frac{1}{z^2}+\sum_{\omega\neq 0} \left(\frac{1}{(z-\omega)^2}-\frac{1}{\omega^2}\right)$$
He said it's a little bit more difficult to verify directly, so we take the derivative
$$\dot{\wp}＝-2\sum_{\omega}\frac{1}{(z-\omega)^3}$$
And then he says that the last one is obviously biperiodic, and I want to know how that works, and how does it work out that the function is biperiodic just because the derivative is biperiodic

Comment: Maybe I didn't describe my question very clearly, but I think I understand what's in the link and what I want to ask is how do you tell that the derivative is biperiodic

Comment: *Hint*: Prove that the series converges locally absolutely uniformly on $\mathbb{C}-\Lambda$ so you can rearrange the order of summation.

Comment: Maybe i just want to find out what those two periods of the series are, is it 1 and the imaginary number i

Comment: There is no reason why $\Lambda$ has to be $\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}i$.  All you know is that $\Lambda$ is a discrete rank-$2$ lattice in $\mathbb{C}$.